# A word for good part of something

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for the correct adjective or noun to describe good part of something.  It could be anything such as a book, a movie, etc.

**Update:**

Take this for example:

> I've skipped a few parts (pages) to get to the [GOOD PART], but I really haven't
>   found any [GOOD PART].

In this context we are speaking of a tutorial video or a scientific book. This [GOOD PART] must have a better synonym. What's the most appropriate and beautiful way of phrasing it?

Comment: What's the context? Can you provide an example sentence? May I ask what words have you considered already?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Updated the question for you

Comment: How would you describe what you consider 'good' about the *good part*? Does it have the equations you're looking for, is it the index (good for looking up things), is it 'objectively' good (e.g. the actual proof in a book purporting to be a proof of *P = NP*) or subjectively good (e.g. pictures, favourite saying)?

Comment: @lawrence, Subjectively good

Comment: Let's say for example, you are eating a pomegranate, hence in doing so, you've gotta take of the peel and other unnecessary parts in order to get in to the good part which is the granular sweet and sour reddies, how would you describe this part of the fruit ?

Comment: I was just about to post an answer - it wouldn't work with fruit, though.

Comment: doesn't matter, that was just an example, please do post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, ***the meat***

> :  the most important part :  substance *Get to the meat of the story.*
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meat)

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, but it's the abstraction, pretty much the word conveys the same meaning, so I'm gonna mark this as an answer, thank you Elian for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

> **Highlight**
>   : something (such as an event or a detail) that is very interesting, exciting, or important : the best part of something - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highlight)

In the context of your sample sentence (slightly edited):

> I've skipped a few parts (pages) to get to the *highlights*, but I really haven't found any.

Comment: closest answer so far, but still not i'm looking for.... what a pity that I can't find the exact word in my notes, perhaps I must review and find it, and definitely post it here!

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor What qualities does your concept have that aren't reflected in the existing answers?

Answer (score 1):

This is where the creation and use of a metaphor might be desirable.

A metaphor, according to the [Merriam-Webster Website](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor), is "*a figure of speech in which a word or phrase literally denoting one kind of object or idea is used in place of another to suggest a likeness or analogy between them (as in drowning in money).*"

Writers often create their own metaphors when they are searching for a figure of speech or an idiom to describe an idea they wish to express, and those already in existence either don't quite fit or sound too dull or cliché.

In this particular context, I would suggest 'cream filling' or 'creamy center,' using a metaphor of a cream-filled donut or Twinkie.

We have all bought a donut or pastry we thought was filled with delightful cream filling, and it turned out to have no filling whatsoever - this would be entirely suitable and comprehensible in this situation.

"Money Shot" is an existing option, if you don't mind a bit of sexual innuendo / metaphorical pornographic reference. [Source: Google](https://www.google.co.th/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=money%20shot%20definition&oq=money%20shot%20definition&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i22i30l8.522.3469.0.3502.22.15.0.0.0.0.274.1825.0j8j3.11.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..11.10.1546.0.gvIikc6Ltjo)

Answer (score 0):

> The important part.
>
> The good bit.
>
> The part that truly matters as opposed to all the maudlin chicklit fluff that precedes it.
>
> The part that finally has sex in it.

Those are your options.

Comment: No, not what i'm looking for.... there's another adjective for it! I just don't recall !

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor: You're very charming and astute.

Comment: That's your kindness..

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor: You ain't seen nothin yet.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

the heart of the matter

the crux

the central issue

the vital part

the critical point

Comment: 'the heart of the matter' is simply the focal point, not the good part, 'crux' is negative or complicated part of a problem, 'the central issue' goes back to the focal point, not the good part, 'vital' is something very necessary, 'critical' is an essential to consider which plays a big role, none of which is implying what i'm looking for, plus what I have stored in my sub-consciousness is a one part word!